# mysql table not updating table - python mysql-connector

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I have the following code to update a url in a table

```
from mysql.connector import Error
import mysql.connector


def update_url(self, data):

    target_url = data['target_url']

    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=os.getenv('mysql_host'),
            port=os.getenv('mysql_port'),
            user=os.getenv('mysql_user'),
            password=os.getenv('mysql_password'),
            database=os.getenv('mysql_database')
        )
        # Create Cursor
        cur = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
        # update target_url
        cur.execute('''UPDATE client_url_info 
                        SET target_url=%s
                        WHERE id=%s''', (data['client_id'], target_url))
        cnx.commit()

        change_url = {
            'status': True,
            'msg': 'Target URL has been successfully updated'
        }

        return change_url
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        change_error_url = {
            'status': 'MYSQL_ERROR',
            'msg': "Failed in MySQL: {}".format(err)
        }
        return change_error_url
    finally:
        if (cnx.is_connected()):
            cnx.close()
```

for some reason I can add data and delete data, but when I try to use update it does not work.

based on other questions, the issue could be cause by the missing of commit() which in my case is included in the code.

I don´t know if I´m not looking right, the code seems to be fine and actually returns the successful msg after execution.

Table info:

[image]

Is there any other configuration I´m missing?

thanks in advance

Comment: You have the parameters in the wrong order. `(data['client_id'], target_url)` should be `(target_url, data['client_id'])`.

Comment: @Barmar outstanding, I don't how why I didn't try that before, I have other function with the same order and works perfectly. Thanks that solve the issue.